# dynamic block branding on django admin start page

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to customize the admin home screen. I tried overwriting `templates/admin/base.html` like this:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block extrahead %}
    TEST #1
{% endblock %}


{% block branding %}
    TEST #2
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

like suggested in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template) but while `TEST #1` works, `TEST #2` does not show up on the admin home page.

**First question**: Why can I not overwrite my branding block, or is this simply the wrong block?

**Second question**: I wish to show information on the main page that comes from the backend - let's for simplicity just say the output of `timezone.now()` - can this be done using a normal `view` in the admin?